# Подключение базы данных в Андроиде

Tags: java, android, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как подключить бд mysql в Андроид?

Comment: Ваш вопрос вызывает слишком много вопросов. Нет уверенности в том, что вам действительно надо именно то, что, как кажется, вы спрашиваете. По умолчанию используют `Sqlite` и IDE тут не при чём. Возможно вы имеете в виду что вам нужен клиент-сервер, где на сервере есть БД? Но в этом случае не важно какая там БД, она должна быть скрыта за API...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хороший ответ, но явно понедельнечный), как по мне будет достаточно ссылки на Room (https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html) или Realm (https://habr.com/ru/post/328418/). Какой вопрос, такой ответ) P.S. когда человек не ленится написать хотя бы задачу, тогда есть смысл раглогольствовать)

Comment: Просто хотя бы что нужно почитать, что бы подключить бд mysql к приложению, мне потом просто эти данные надо будут для вывода на сайт

Comment: @Valeriy, я не уверен, что ТС нужна мобильная БД. Раз речь идёт про наполнение БД для сайта, то, видимо, ему нужно что-то типа JDBC, однако оно, как говорят, плохо работает... Хотя, может, и работает. Но даже если так, то надо будет в приложение встраивать логин/пароль от БД, что ппц как небезопасно. Однако, если это учебный проект, то, может быть и прокатит. Возможно, всё проблема в том, что вопрос надо было формулировать так: `как подключить**СЯ** к бд mysql с Андроида?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Android не поддерживается стандартный Java механизм подключения БД через JDBC.

Штатная БД SQLite работает через другой механизм - `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Таким образом подключение БД MySQL возможно только через HTTP/Json. То есть над MySQL должна быть обертка, которая вызовы HTTP/Json переводит в язык понятный MySQL и возвращает ответ в виде Json